# It is possible to relate a pivot table to another pivot table in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, pivot, relationship

- plans

  - id
  - name
- posts

  - id
  - title
- users

  - id
  - name
- categories

  - id
  - name
- plan_post //BelongsToMany

  - plan_id
  - post_id
- plan_user //BelongsToMany

  - id
  - plan_id
  - user_id
- I need to relate a category to the pan_user record ...
- plan_user_category // what ???

  - plan_user_id
  - category_id

Comment: Hi - for readability, could you explain your question in the body too, rather than just in a comment in your model please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be no such relationship. If you have a pivot table, it binds two tables that are not pivot.

What is a pivot table? This is a table that has no increments. And it binds to the increments of tables for which it is a pivot. If the table has increments then it does not automatically pivot.

```
plan_user_category // what ???

 plan_user_id // BelongsTo or BelongsToMany -> plan_user
 category_id // BelongsTo or BelongsToMany -> categories
```

---

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a plan - user - category relationships.

If so, make the following tables:

- plans (id, ...)
- users_plans (user_id, plan_id)
- users (id, ...)
- users_categories (user_id, category_id)
- categories (id, ...)

and that from plans to get to categories it is necessary to build relationships through models

```
class Plans
public function users() 
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_plans', 'user_id', 'plan_id');
}

class User
public function categories() 
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'users_catogories', 'category_id', 'user_id');
}

foreach($plans->users() as $user) {
  $categories[] = $user->categories();
}
```

Comment: I understand, the problem is that when I synchronize the table plan_user I need to set a category reference, do you have any suggestions?